# Validating CheckBox in Form with jQuery Script http://validator.codeplex.com/

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form using the script from here http://validator.codeplex.com.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="input" autocomplete="on">
    <fieldset>              
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  maxlength="60" validate="form" require="Please enter your name." />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""  maxlength="80" validate="form" require="Please enter your email address." email="Please enter a valid email address." />
        <input type="url" name="url" id="url" value=""  maxlength="400" validate="form" require="Please enter your website." />
        <input type="checkbox" id="updates" name="updates"  />
        <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree"  validate="form" require="Please agree to the terms."/>
        <input type='submit' value=""  id="submit" onclick="return validate('form');" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

All the fields are validated correctly, except for the checkbox. I am not sure how to validate the checkbox part correctly using the script. Any thoughts?

Also - here is the javascript part: http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/TBtSD/

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried asking in the project forum? You might get a direct response from the developer.

Comment: consider using some better plugin like validate.js

Comment: Thanks @john. I really like the look of the validator that I posted... so I was hoping to just make it work. Why is validate.js a better plugin?

Comment: @Ori because it can validate the check boxes `;)` also its been widely used or i have seen it been used by a lot of developers in a lot of projects, its maintained actively and many more... i have posted an answer with your provided markup in case it interests you

Answer (score 1):

as @jrummell has mentioned in the comments that asking at the plugin's support would be more beneficial, if it an option i would suggest to switch to [**`validate.js`**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SAfBm/) with your markup

Comment: It's actually called `jQuery Validate`.

Answer (score 1):

In the validator script add the two lines as marked out below:

```
function check(elm) {
  var jelm = $(elm);

  var listsize = jelm.find("input:radio, input:checkbox").size();
  if (jelm.attr("disabled") || listsize > 0 && listsize == jelm.find("input:radio:disabled, input:checkbox:disabled").size())
    return "";

  //ADD THESE TWO LINES
  if (jelm.attr("require") && jelm.is(":checkbox:not(':checked')"))
    return "require";
  //------------------------

  //if empty value only perform required validation
  if ((jelm.val() == "" || jelm.val() == null) && jelm.find("input:radio:checked, input:checkbox:checked").size() == 0)
    return jelm.attr("require") ? "require" : "";
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much for commenting on this. Sorry I just saw your response.

Could you please clarify what I need to do in the HTML part:

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" name="agree-to-terms" require="make sure to check" />

Comment: And in the jquery.validator.js part?

    function check(elm) {
     var jelm = $(elm);
   
     var listsize = jelm.find("input:radio, input:checkbox").size();
     if (jelm.attr("disabled") || listsize > 0 && listsize == jelm.find("input:radio:disabled, input:checkbox:disabled").size())
      return "";
   
     //if empty value only perform required validation
   
     if (jelm.attr("require") && jelm.is(":checkbox:not(':checked')"))
      return "require";

Comment: @Ori the jquery.validator.js part is correct (updated my answer to make more clear), although for the HTML part you've forgotten to put the `validate="form"` attribute on your checkbox in your comment.

Comment: @Ori just so you know I think the value for the validate attribute can be changed if you need a second form on the page, e.g. `<input type="text" validate="contactForm" />, <input type="submit" onclick="return validate('contactForm');" />`

Comment: Hi @Michael - thanks so much for your help. I don't know what I'm missing... but for some reason it's not working for me.. Here is my script (http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/HfwM4/)

When I click submit, I get the validation pop up for all fields except for the check box. You won't be able to see it in the preview I sent because it's not configured right but I just added the code in there because it's easier. Please let me know if you have a solution - you will be a life saver!!!

Comment: @Ori the html all looks fine, however in jsfiddle under "choose framework" you need to select "no wrap (body)" & "jquery" instead of "onbody" "mootools" so that is why it's failing there.

Comment: Although what you're probably noticing on your site is the checkbox is not highlighted after clicking the button, this is because the default styling simply changes the background-color to yellow which doesn't work on a checkbox. But the yellow popup still appears next to it if it's the last field and you click the button. So if you want to make it more obvious place a sentence next to the checkbox and wrap both in a span tag with the validation attributes on it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/HfwM4/8/ Then the sentence can show the background-color. Also you wouldn't need my fix anymore.